# Manga where the female lead travels to different dimensions to fix the lives of different side characters

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, isekai

Does anyone know a manga where the female lead is in a system where she travels into different dimensions? She possesses the bodies of side characters who die and takes revenge using their bodies and then returns to her own body. I think her sidekick is a system cat like. She travels to medieval and modern dimensions to fix the lives of different side characters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Can you add some details on the revenge, or some specific examples? Random guess: Cheating Men Must Die. From the synopsis it sounds like a match, but without any detail I can't tell if this is it or if there's another multiworld revenge-themed manga.

Comment: @ qazmlpok. OMG! yes! Thanks soo much. This is it. I read it a really long time ago and totally forgot the title.

Answer (score 4):

As confirmed in the comments, this is *[Cheating Men Must Die](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/cheating-men-must-die)*.

> One moment oppressing scum yields a moment of satisfaction. Continuously oppressing scum yields continuous satisfaction. Our female main lead, Su Lüxia is bound to the Female Lead Counterattack System and **transmigrates to several small worlds**. Using elaborate means, she beats up countless cheating bastards and bitches. Su Lüxia: "Only a cheating bastard's tears of remorse, and the pained moans of a bitch unable to get what she wants bring me solace." System: "Has my host tapped into her humanity today? Nope."